# How to work around case sensitivity of HEX values?

Tags: theme-customizer

Setting up the WP Customizer options, where it only writes CSS to the head if the value is not the default for that setting. BUT... sometimes the customizer will save the HEX value in all caps and other times it's lowercase. The defaults are all set as capitalized values, and even if it appears they're capitalized values in the customizer itself, it will still sometimes print lowercase HEX values in the CSS, adding unnecessary code.

Is there a way to override the case-sensitivity of HEX values in this instance?

```
$cssoutput = '';

////* save the styles to the cssoutput
if ( $bg !== '#F5F5F5' ) {
    $cssoutput .=
        "body { background-color: " . $bg . "; } \n";
}
if ( $title !== '#333333' ) {
    $cssoutput .=
        ".site-title a { color: " . $title . "; } \n";
}
echo 
"<style type=\"text/css\">" . $cssoutput . "</style>";
```

Results in this when it shouldn't be writing the value at all -

```
<style type="text/css">body { background-color: #f5f5f5; } </style>
```

Also, I should note it appears to be a random action, some mixed HEX values are all capitalized and others are lowercase, even if they're all entered and saved as capital values.

Comment: Where is that code from?

Comment: This is a generic PHP problem that does not invlove wp-core. These type of question better fits sites like stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more basic PHP than WordPress, but you can do a case insensitive search using `strcasecmp()`.

```
if ( strcasecmp( $bg, '#F5F5F5' ) != 0 ) {
  $cssoutput .= "body { background-color: " . $bg . "; } \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Force the case:

```
$bg = strtoupper( $bg );
```

Now compare it against the uppercase default, the case of the colour itself is now irrelevant, as it will always be uppercase ( because you made it so )